# How to select every first parent list item coming before selected list item

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li class="selected">three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

In this situation, How to selected "li" having text "two". with CSS or jQuery.
Please Help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.prev()` method:

```
$('li.selected').prev();
```

Comment: @unconfidentDownvoter care to explain the reason of downvoting?

Answer (score 2):

One option is the `:contains` selector.

```
 $("li:contains('two')")
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = $('li').filter(function() {
  return ($(this).text() == 'two');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery nth child selector:

```
var li = $('ul#myul li:nth-child(2n)');
```